# 23.04 - Stuck Notifications

Tags: gnome, notification, notification-area

When I get notifications, mostly from Chrome, they end up stuck at the top of the screen. I cannot dismiss them or acknowledge them. Usually, it'll be a few, i dismiss them, but one stays persistent just under the date/time.

The only way I have found that I can get rid of them is actually rebooting...

Any suggestions? How to restart the notification services may help.